# What is the best method to find number of working months in given date ranges

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, date

I have a requirement that find the number of effective working months on given date ranges. Where as

```
effective working month = Number of working days work per month/ total working days of that month

working days considered as days without weekends.
```

Current algorithm we use is that

```
   Total working months= number of working months in first month + number of working months in last month + number of months in between
```

Here we were able to simplify our calculation to work without any loop. However the code is long and consist of many functions. unfortunately due to sensitivity of the information, i can't post the code here. I would be grateful if someone can enlighten me a better algorithm to increase the efficiency of the code  to the fullest because performance is top most priority for us.

```
//Unit test would be start date = 2020-05-20 , end date = 2021-08-11 expected result is 14.74458875

Number of months in first month  = workingDays(2020-05-20,2020-05-31)/workingdays(2020-05-01,2020-05-31)
                                 = 0.380952381 
Number of months in last month   = workingDays(2021-08-01,2021-08-11)/workingdays(2021-08-01,2021-08-31) 
                                  = 0.363636364
months in between = 14
total months = 0.380952381 +14+0.363636364
= 14.74458875
```

Comment: It sounds like you're after the number of working ___days___ between 2 dates, not months!!!

Comment: @phuzi: no, not with the proposed test of `('2020-05-20', '2021-08-11')` supposed to yield  `14.744588744588745`

Comment: Do you include either or both endpoints in your calculation?

Comment: Is it weeks then? "number of working months in first month" doesn't make sense, if it's weeks, does it really matter if it's working or not?!

Comment: I want number of working months between 2 dates. example . in my unit test 20th may to 31 may is 0.380952381

Comment: I will put example to be more clear

Comment: Can you add an example showing each step with values rather than just the end result?

Comment: I have now put an example of the sample case

Comment: How you know which day was weekend.. only 2 days per week without govt. holiday?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that does something similar to the algorithm you describe.  I have no idea if it cleans up the code for you or if it performs better:

```js
// General-purpose utility functions

const range = (lo, hi) => 
  [... Array (hi - lo + 1)] .map ((_, i) => lo + i)

const parseDate = (s, [y, m, d] = s.split('-') .map (Number)) => 
  [y, m -1 , d]  // m - 1 because JS Dates are screwy about months

const isLeapYear = (y) => 
  (y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0 || y % 400 == 0)

const daysInMonth = (y, m) => 
  isLeapYear (y)
    ? [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] [m]
    : [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] [m]

// Helper functions

const fullMonthsBetween = (y1, m1, y2, m2) => // excludes both endpoints
  Math.max((12 * y2 + m2) - (12 * y1 + m1) - 1, 0)

const workingDaysInRemainderOfMonth = (y, m, d, day = new Date (y, m, d) .getDay ()) => 
  range (d, daysInMonth (y, m)) 
    .filter ((_, i) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] .includes((day + i) % 7)) 
    .length

const workingDaysInStartOfMonth = (y, m, d) =>
  range (1, d) 
    .filter ((_, i) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] .includes ((d + i) % 7)) 
    .length

// Main function

const workingMonthsBetween = (start, end) => {
  const [y1, m1, d1] = parseDate (start)
  const [y2, m2, d2] = parseDate (end)
  return fullMonthsBetween (y1, m1, y2, m2)
         + workingDaysInRemainderOfMonth (y1, m1, d1) 
            / workingDaysInRemainderOfMonth(y1, m1, 1)
         + workingDaysInStartOfMonth (y2, m2, d2)
            / workingDaysInRemainderOfMonth(y2, m2, 1)
}

// Demo
console .log (
  workingMonthsBetween ('2020-05-20', '2021-08-12')  //~> 14.744588744588745
)
```

There a number of small functions here.  Most could be inlined to improve performance, but I prefer to work with many small helper functions than a big monolith, so I'll leave that to you.

- **`range`** creates an integer range.  `range (3, 12) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`
- **`parseDate`** converts a string like `'2020-08-12'` into the year/month/day fields `[2010, 7, 12]`.  That is not a typo.  The rest of JS date processing uses a 0-indexed month, so we subtract one here.
- **`isLeapYear`** should be obvious, although the leap year rules are slightly complicated
- **`daysInMonth`** accepts a year and month and returns the total number of days in the month, taking the leap year into account
- **`fullMonthsBetween`** reports the number of months strictly between two year/month combinations.  Thus between 2020-05 and 2020-09, there are three months, June, July, and August.
- **`workingDaysInRemainderOfMonth`** takes a year, month, and date and reports how many working days are left in that month (including our given date and the last day of the month).  It does this by filtering out all Saturdays (6 mod 7) and Sundays (0 mod 7) from the range of days between this date and the last day of the month.  We could probably do some interesting arithmetic to calculate the initial day of the week and avoid using the date constructor here, but that would take some deeper thinking.
- **`workingDaysInStartOfMonth`** does something similar for the days between the first of the month and the given date.
- **`workingMonthsBetween`** is the main function, which takes two ISO-8601-formatted date strings and computes the number of months between them using the various helper functions above.

All this of course ignores holidays.  While it wouldn't be extraordinarily difficult to add them, it's not trivial either.

### Update

I looked into using [Zeller's Congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence), and while I have no idea if that does much to speed up the whole algorithm, it's [significantly faster](https://jsperf.com/get-day-of-week) in isolation than using the Date constructor.  The following snippet shows this alternative.

```js
// General-purpose utility functions
const range = (lo, hi) => 
  [... Array (hi - lo + 1)] .map ((_, i) => lo + i)

const parseDate = (s, [y, m, d] = s.split('-') .map (Number)) => 
  [y, m - 1, d]

const isLeapYear = (y) => 
  (y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0 || y % 400 == 0)

const daysInMonth = (y, m) => 
  isLeapYear (y)
    ? [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] [m]
    : [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] [m]

// Zeller's Congruence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence)
const dayOfWeek = (
  year, month, date,
  y = month < 3 ? year - 1 : year,
  m = ((month + 9) % 12) + 3
) => (
  date 
  + Math .floor ((13 * m - 1) / 5)
  + Math .floor (y / 4)
  - Math .floor (y / 100) 
  + Math .floor (y / 400)
) % 7

  
// Helper functions
const fullMonthsBetween = (y1, m1, y2, m2) => // excludes both endpoints
  Math.max((12 * y2 + m2) - (12 * y1 + m1) - 1, 0)

const workingDaysInRemainderOfMonth = (y, m, d, day = dayOfWeek(y, m + 1, d)) => 
  range (d, daysInMonth (y, m)) 
    .filter ((_, i) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] .includes((day + i) % 7)) 
    .length

const workingDaysInStartOfMonth = (y, m, d) =>
  range (1, d) 
    .filter ((_, i) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] .includes ((d + i) % 7)) 
    .length


// Main function
const workingMonthsBetween = (start, end) => {
  const [y1, m1, d1] = parseDate (start)
  const [y2, m2, d2] = parseDate (end)
  return fullMonthsBetween (y1, m1, y2, m2)
         + workingDaysInRemainderOfMonth (y1, m1, d1) 
            / workingDaysInRemainderOfMonth(y1, m1, 1)
         + workingDaysInStartOfMonth (y2, m2, d2)
            / workingDaysInRemainderOfMonth(y2, m2, 1)
}


// Demo
console .log (
  workingMonthsBetween ('2020-05-20', '2021-08-12')  //~> 14.744588744588745
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your explanation and took time to explain it. Size doesn't matter if i get faster performance. thank you

Comment: If you're interested in performance, I found that manually checking the day of the week using [Zeller's Congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) is significantly faster than the above: https://jsperf.com/get-day-of-week.  You would have to slightly modify something to use it, because it uses standard months rather than JS 0-base ones, but that should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the function below. It treats both dates in the same way, each in one iteration of the loop. For easing the counting, a pattern string is used, which has "x" for working days. After getting the right substring from that pattern, the non-x characters (weekend days) are removed from it, so that the resulting length represents a number of working days. The rest is just adding things up:

```js
function workingDays(fromDate, toDate) {
    let monthCount = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        let date = i ? toDate : fromDate;
        let year = +date.slice(0, 4);
        let month = date.slice(5, 7) - 1;
        let day = +date.slice(8);
        let weekday = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
        let pattern = ":xxxxx::xxxxx::xxxxx::xxxxx::xxxxx::x"
                .slice(weekday, weekday + new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate());
        monthCount += (year * 12 + month) * (i ? 1 : -1) 
           + pattern.slice(i ? 0 : day - 1, i ? day : 31).replace(/:/g, "").length
             / pattern.replace(/:/g, "").length;
    }
    return monthCount;
}

// The "unit test" example from the question
console.log(workingDays("2020-05-20", "2021-08-11")); // 14.7445887445...
```

Comment: This looks wayyy cleaner and faster much appreciate @trincot . let me compare the other codes in terms of performance.